# Django ORM: Select rows by distinct column value

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

This may sound like a silly question but I just can't figure out how to convert this simple query into django queryset.

```
select distinct locality, id from shootsta_bookings.users_useraddress;
```

I've tried this:

```
    @list_route(methods=['GET'], url_path='locations')
    def locations(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        **localities = models.UserAddress.objects.all().values('locality').distinct()**

        data = self.get_serializer(localities, many=True, context={'request': request}).data

        return response.Ok(data)
```

But it only returns the distinct values `without the ids`.

Here's my serializer if that helps:

```
class LocationListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserAddress
        fields = [
            'id',
            'locality',
        ]
```

I'm looking for a clean solution without having to filter the queryset with `in` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Distinct *(id, locality)* tuples

You should add the `id` to the values, like:

```
localities = models.UserAddress.objects.values('id', 'locality').distinct()
```

## Distinct localities with id

If you want to return the `id` together with the `locality` such that the `localities` are distinct, we can work with a subquery, like:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery

locs = Subquery(UserAddress.objects.values('locality').distinct())

localities = models.UserAddress.objects.filter(
    locality__in=locs
).values('id', 'locality')
```

If you use a *PostgreSQL* database, you can do this simpler by using [**`distinct()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) where you can specify the column name that should be distinct:

```
localities = models.UserAddress.objects.values('id', 'locality').distinct('locality')
```

Comment: Works thanks. And I realized that getting ids of distinct values wouldn't be of any use to me. Plus I wanted a flat list of values. So this worked for me:

`queryset = models.UserAddress.objects.values_list('locality', flat=True).distinct()`
and then
`localities = list(queryset)`